# Javascript function in React gives error but works in normal HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My JS File:

```
function getBlogInfo(){
url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api_key=my-api-key",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(info){
      console.log(info);
      console.log(info.response.blog.likes);
    }
  }

 export getBlogInfo();
```

My React Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getBlogInfo } from './scripts/apiCalls';

class Homepage extends Component {
       componentDidMount(){
        getBlogInfo();
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage">

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

The Error I get is:

```
./src/components/scripts/apiCalls.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; (3:12)

  1 | function getBlogInfo(){
  2 | url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api_key=my-api-key",
> 3 |     dataType: 'jsonp',
    |             ^
  4 |     success: function(info){
  5 |       console.log(info);
  6 |       console.log(info.response.blog.likes);
```

This script works when used without reactjs in normal HTML. It is supposed to print the info in the console.

Comment: I am very confused - your `getBlogInfo()` function block does not appear to be valid JavaScript; you are missing a brace, there is no actual request being sent via `fetch()` or other means

Comment: I hope you are trying to write an ajax method there. and you probably missed it in your getBlogInfo method. can you post what did you write in normal HTML?

Comment: There is something wrong with the code. I think you are missing the ajax code. The error is completely correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I fixed the ajax mistake and now am getting a new error - Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (10:0)

   8 |     }
   9 |   }
> 10 | }  
     | ^
  11 | 
  12 | export getBlogInfo();

Comment: isnt it export function? Which line is giving you exception? Can you update your question with new error?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to return an object, below is the syntax to return an object, to access this function in other file it must be exported.

```
export function getBlogInfo(){
  return {
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api_key=my-api-key",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(info){
      console.log(info);
      console.log(info.response.blog.likes);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it turns out it was a missing ajax call, which I have now fixed, but a new error has popped up - Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (10:0)

   8 |     }
   9 |   }
> 10 | }  
     | ^
  11 | 
  12 | export getBlogInfo();

Comment: use export keyword along with function definition to access the function in other files